# Vue3 pass component as prop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

i'm building a tab component where i need to pass component as a prop.

how can i display the component passed in the props?

Tab.vue

```html
<template>
  <div class="bg-white flex items-center rounded-tr rounded-tl shadow border-b border-grey overflow-hidden">
    <button @click="activeTab = title" v-for="title in titles" v-text="title"
            class="font-medium px-4 py-3 hover:bg-grey hover:bg-opacity-70 border-b-2 border-transparent hover:border-primary"
            :class="title === activeTab && 'border-primary bg-grey bg-opacity-70 '"/>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-white p-4 min-h-[calc(100vh-10rem)]">
    <component :is="activeTab"></component> // not working
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
import {onMounted, ref} from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
  titles: {},
  tabs: {}
})
const activeTab = ref("")
onMounted(() => {
  activeTab.value = props.titles[0]
})
</script>
```

Settings.vue

```html
<template>
  <Tab :titles="[$t('languagesLabel'),$t('countriesLabel')]" :tabs="[Languages,Countries]">
  </Tab>
</template>
<script setup>
import Tab from "../../components/admin/common/Tab.vue";
import Countries from "../../components/admin/settings/Countries.vue";
import Languages from "../../components/admin/settings/Languages.vue";
</script>
```

the question is how to make the displayed component dynamic ?

Answer (score 4):

When using `<script setup>`, the `<component>.is` prop needs to be set to the component definition itself (not the component's name).

One solution is to track the active index (instead of active tab component):

1. Change `activeTab` to be a computed prop that returns the current tab from `tabs[]` based on the active index.
2. Create an `activeIndex` ref, initialized to `0`.
3. In the `v-for`, include the `index` iterator
4. In the `button`'s `click` handler, set the `activeIndex` to the current `index`.
5. In the `class` binding, compare the current `index` to `activeIndex`.

```html
<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref, computed } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
  titles: {},
  tabs: {},
})
         1️⃣
const activeTab = computed(() => props.tabs[activeIndex.value])
         2️⃣
const activeIndex = ref(0)
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="bg-white flex items-center rounded-tr rounded-tl shadow border-b border-grey overflow-hidden">
    <button
                       3️⃣
      v-for="(title, index) in titles"
                  4️⃣
      @click="activeIndex = index"
      v-text="title"
      class="font-medium px-4 py-3 hover:bg-grey hover:bg-opacity-70 border-b-2 border-transparent hover:border-primary"
                 5️⃣
      :class="index === activeIndex && 'text-red border-primary bg-grey bg-opacity-70 '"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="bg-white p-4 min-h-[calc(100vh-10rem)]">
    <component :is="activeTab"></component>
  </div>
</template>
```

Also, make sure to call [`markRaw()`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#markraw) on the component definitions in the binding to avoid the unnecessary overhead of reactivity. This also resolves a  Vue warning about this in the browser console.

```html
<template>                                                       
  <Tab :titles="['Languages', 'Countries']" :tabs="[languages, countries]"> </Tab>
</template>
<script setup>
import { markRaw } from 'vue'
import Tab from '@/components/Tab.vue'
import Countries from '@/components/Countries.vue'
import Languages from '@/components/Languages.vue'
                     
const countries = markRaw(Countries)
const languages = markRaw(Languages)
</script>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-component-as-prop?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FSettings.vue)